# Optimistic Update using localStorage. Is this bad design?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, concurrency

**Scenario:**

So I have a javascript component that basically holds an instance of some global list of data (In my actual application, this resides in a Flux Store, but I'm just referring it as a global variable for simplicity's sake).

It contains functions to ADD/DELETE data by making AJAX calls to a REST API.

**Design:**

Since I want the users to be able to immediately view the updated list, instead of having to wait until the Ajax success callback, I'm performing an "Optimistic Update."

That is, I'm updating the list before performing the actual AJAX call, while keeping the original copy of the list in localStorage in case the AJAX call fails.

(1) If the AJAX call succeeds, then update the list with the API response (which should basically be the same as the optimistically updated list)

(2) If the AJAX call fails, then undo the optimistic update by retrieving the original copy from the localStorage.

Here is my **Implementation**:

```
// Some global data list
var myData = ["data1", "data2", ...];

function addData(dataToAdd) {
    // Store original in cache before optimistic update
    localStorage.set("MY_DATA", myData);
    // Do optimistic update
    myData = myData.concat(dataToAdd);

    $.ajax({
        url: REST_API_ADD,
        method: "POST",
        data: { data: dataToAdd },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) { 
            // API returns the updated list when success
            myData = response;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) { 
            console.log(err);
            // Cancel optimistic update and retrieve old data from cache
            myData = localStorage.get("MY_DATA");
        }
    }); 
}

function deleteData(dataToDelete) {
    // Store original in cache before optimistic update
    localStorage.set("MY_DATA", myData);
    // Do optimistic update
    // I'm using Underscore.js here to delete data from list
    myData = _.without(
        myData,
        _.findWhere(myData, {id: dataToDelete.id})
    );

    $.ajax({
        url: REST_API_DELETE,
        method: "DELETE",
        data: { data: dataToDelete },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) { 
            // API returns the updated list when success
            myData = response;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) { 
            console.log(err);
            // Cancel optimistic update and retrieve old data from cache
            myData = localStorage.get("MY_DATA");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this idea?

My primary concern is a race condition that might occur when the user performs ADD and DELETE operations almost simultaneously..

I've thought of possible scenarios, but it seems like concurrency is not a problem in my case, since the callback functions never modify the localStorage. All they do is "get."

Can anyone think of situations where my design might cause problems?

Is this a bad design overall? If so, then can you suggest an alternative approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> My primary concern is a race condition that might occur when the user
>   performs ADD and DELETE operations almost simultaneously..

There should be no concern here since AJAX executed from the UI thread isn't *asynchronous* in terms of parallelism. Web browsers use an execution queue where each enqueued action is dequeued synchronously.

For example, it will never happen that you modify the DOM and perform an AJAX request concurrently. Actually, UI tasks have more priority than AJAX, but anyway they will be executed one by one.

AFAIK, there's only one chance that you will run in concurrency problems: [*Web workers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Unless you use them, you're absolutely safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a bad design, but you can still have more control over users. At least you can block them from taking another action while an ajax call waiting for success.

I can think of one problem: If you are dealing with lots of data, writing to and reading from the localStorage may lead to performance problems.

Besides these, there should be no problems at all within your approach.